# Show UserControl in Popoup

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I have a button and another control placed in a usercontrol
I want to pop out the control below the button to the topp of all other controls when the bitton in the usercontrol is clicked
[image]

Comment: Perhaps this can help: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9508/Display-any-usercontrol-as-a-popup-menu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can host any kind of `Control` in a [`ToolStripControlHost`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripcontrolhost(v=vs.110).aspx) and then add it to items of [ToolStripDropDown](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripdropdown(v=vs.110).aspx) and then show the dropdown:

```
Dim dropdown As ToolStripDropDown = New ToolStripDropDown()
Dim c As UserControl1 = New UserControl1()
Dim host As ToolStripControlHost = New ToolStripControlHost(c)
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
    Handles Button2.Click
    If (dropdown.Items.Count = 0) Then
        host.BackColor = Color.White
        host.Margin = New Padding(2)
        c.MinimumSize = New Size(120, 100)
        dropdown.Padding = New Padding(0)
        dropdown.Margin = New Padding(0)
        dropdown.Items.Add(host)
    End If
    dropdown.Show(Button2, 0, Button1.Height)
End Sub
```

[image: DropDown]

Comment: thanks, but you get it wrong. the button and the checklist are both in the usercontrol, the size of the usercontrol is the size of the button. i will be adding the code inside the usercontrol that host the button and the checklist.

Comment: No problem, I suppose your controls (except button) are in a panel. So, do the job using that panel.

Comment: the usecontrol is auto resized based on content, and as such i cannot specify an explicit size as you did `c.MinimumSize = New Size(120, 100)`, how do i solve this, and where did you add items to the `dropdown` in your code?

Comment: I checked it using auto-size and it seems it doesn't have problem. But it's better to keep a minimum and maximum size for the menu/control.