# How to show popup winform over textbox

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio

Hello I'm developing software, but I want to code like this:

[image: Here the screenshoot.]

When textbox customer clicked, an small form will showing like pop up.

How to show pop up over textbox, that will be show up a small form when textbox is clicked. Is it a plug in? Or code?
If is it a plug in control, what is the name of control like that?

Thank you,

Comment: It's a form. It's like any other form. There's no magic to it whatsoever.

Comment: @jmcilhinney So how to showing up another form over textbox position likw pop up? Thanks

Comment: It looks like a simple dialog.  The only "magic" is that you want to position it.  Go forth and Google after you read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: suggest a look at [FastColoredTextBox](https://github.com/PavelTorgashov/FastColoredTextBox), it must have something you want

Comment: @LeiYang that's a completely unrelated topic to that discussed here. @MEgiver, `FormBorderStyle` and `Location` properties are worth a look, as well as looking into the Graphics class if you want to really go deep.

Comment: @AlexM. I don't think it is unrelated. at least a editor's intelligence is like a Form/adorner, which the OP is looking for!

Comment: @LeiYang it's a custom drawn control which behaves nothing like a form...

Comment: and I don't think the OP needs a real Form, nor does the picture needs to be.

Comment: I just confused, I have searching but is nothing. No one topic that discuss about the form with no border style show over combo/textbox. I think it not only show hide another form with spesific position. But I guess there a some another way. Here the videos      https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MzU6Hm6idK0

Thanks for advance.

Comment: The reason you're not finding information is because you're looking for something too specific. Think it through. Break the problem down into parts and then research each part independently. You know that you need to display a form in a specific position so research that. Once you can do that, you then know that you need to calculate that position based on the location of the `TextBox`, so research that. Etc. The issue here is the exoectation that there will be some turnkey solution to every specific scenario encountered. There won't. It's up to you to put the pieces together.

Comment: I think its a form with showDialog, have you tried this?

Comment: It can be created by a user control which is hosted in `ContextMenuStrip`. For example take a look at this post: [Datagridview shall disappear when clicking on the Form in the background](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38703523/3110834) or this one [Popout control from user control .net](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38996397/3110834).

Comment: @RezaAghaei Aha! this is I mean for answer, Thanks Dude!.  Not yet to try but I will mark as answered.