# What is the equivalent control in WindowsForms for the ContentControl in WPF?

Tags: winforms, popup

I need to create the popup control for my custom control in WinForms. I have a refernce for doing it by using the ContentControl in WPF.

But I cannot find the ContentControl in WinForms. Is there any other alternative control can be used instead of the ContentControl in WinForms.

Comment: Are you looking for `ToolStripControlHost` like [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38996397/3110834) or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38703523/3110834)?

Comment: @RezaAghaei Thanks for your suggestion. It helps for me to add my filter control as a popup control.